# What is the green <92> that's in my file?

Tags: grep, ascii, file

I have a file exported from some system, and in vi when I open the file, there's a green `<92>` in it when I open it up where an `'` ought to be.

It messed up my bash script and left a line that reads `Binary file (standard input) matches` after I `grep'd` it.

When I run `file` against it, it says the file is encoded as `Non-ISO extended-ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators`

What is that green `<92>` and why is it binary and messing up grep?

Comment: This sounds like an encoding issue. Use the `ga` command in vim (or the text-filter `xxd` from your shell) to get a good look at the actual data in the file, then decide what encoding is appropriate, or what happened.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Is there a way to search for these?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Some CTRL+V sort of a thing?

Comment: Search for what?

Comment: The green `<92>` (it occurs more than once).

Comment: Yea, use `<C-v>u` followed by the unicode number that you got from `ga`

Answer (score 1):

This is a [win-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) quote character which means you're not using the correct encoding. See Unicode characters 2018 and [2019](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_single_quotation_mark). The encoding is also called CP1252.

In most other encodings, characters between 0x80 and 0x9F are viewed as "graphical controls". Microsoft wanted to add a few more characters to the ISO-8859-1 (probably to have a "better experience" in MS-Word and such where those characters are used a lot). That was a time when writing characters in a word processor or on the screen was not capable of handling a font with more than 256 characters. So having *all* the characters cramped up in one encoding was useful.

On my end, I often have to change those into code point 0x27 ('), i.e. the [apostrophe character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostrophe#Unicode).