# How to list the hex range of an a fileencoding in vim?

Tags: range

Is there any way to take a `fileencoding` setting (for instance utf8 or cp1252) that you might set and find out what it's valid hex range is?

When a character falls outside the range, it is displayed with a `<XY>` [hex code in the file](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/22299/what-is-the-green-92-thats-in-my-file), so vim knows what the range is, but how do I the user display it?

Comment: @Would looking at vim’s source code reveal anything?

Comment: Better perhaps to google the fileencodings